CSP report endpoint problem in ASP.NET Core
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where I need to handle Content Security Policy (CSP) violation reports. I have set up a CSP header to report violations to a specific endpoint and created a corresponding controller to handle the reports. However, I'm encountering issues with deserializing the incoming JSON payload. Despite setting the Content-Type to application/csp-report, the request object in my controller action is null, and the properties of my model are not being populated correctly.
Setup details:
CSP Header Middleware:
I added a middleware to set the CSP header, which includes the report-uri directive:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; report-uri /csp-report;");
        await next();
    });

    // Other middleware...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

Controller to Handle CSP Reports:
I created a controller to handle POST requests at the /csp-report endpoint:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using APP.APP1.Entities.Definitions.CspReporting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace APP.APP1.UI.Controllers
{
    [Route("csp-report")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CspReportController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CspReportController> _logger;

        public CspReportController(ILogger<CspReportController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult CspReport([FromBody] CspReportRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null || request.CspReport == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid CSP report");
            }

            // Log the CSP report
            _logger.LogWarning($"CSP Violation: Document URI: {request.CspReport.DocumentUri}, Blocked URI: {request.CspReport.BlockedUri}");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

Model classes: my model classes for deserializing the CSP report:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace APP.APP1.Entities.Definitions.CspReporting
{
    public class CspReportRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("cspReport")]
        public CspReport CspReport { get; set; }
    }

    public class CspReport
    {
        [JsonProperty("document-uri")]
        public string DocumentUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("referrer")]
        public string Referrer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("blocked-uri")]
        public string BlockedUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("violated-directive")]
        public string ViolatedDirective { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("effective-directive")]
        public string EffectiveDirective { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("original-policy")]
        public string OriginalPolicy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("disposition")]
        public string Disposition { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status-code")]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("script-sample")]
        public string ScriptSample { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("line-number")]
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("column-number")]
        public int ColumnNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source-file")]
        public string SourceFile { get; set; }
    }
}

Configuring the input formatter: in Startup.cs, I configured the SystemTextJsonInputFormatter to support the application/csp-report media type:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Linq;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters.OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>().First();
        jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
    });

    // Other service registrations...
}

To test the endpoint, I used the following JavaScript code to send a CSP violation report:
fetch('/csp-report', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/csp-report'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        cspReport: {
            "document-uri": "http://example.com/test",
            "referrer": "",
            "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
            "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
            "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';",
            "disposition": "report",
            "blocked-uri": "http://malicious.com/script.js",
            "line-number": 1,
            "column-number": 1,
            "source-file": "http://example.com/test"
        }
    })
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        console.log("CSP report sent successfully.");
    } else {
        console.error("Failed to send CSP report.");
    }
});

Problem
Despite configuring everything, the CspReportRequest object in the controller action remains null, and the properties of the CspReport object are not being populated correctly.
Here is the payload sent in the request:
{
    "cspReport": {
        "document-uri": "http://example.com/test",
        "referrer": "",
        "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
        "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';",
        "disposition": "report",
        "blocked-uri": "http://malicious.com/script.js",
        "line-number": 1,
        "column-number": 1,
        "source-file": "http://example.com/test"
    }
}

Error observed: the request object in the controller action is null, resulting in a 400 Bad Request response:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|553d9216-43a24081a09550b4."
}

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the JSON structure matches the model properties.
Added JsonProperty attributes to match the JSON property names.
Configured SystemTextJsonInputFormatter to support the application/csp-report media type.
Verified that the payload is correctly structured.

Question: how can I correctly deserialize the incoming application/csp-report payload into my CspReportRequest model in ASP.NET Core?
Additional Context:

ASP.NET Core 5.0
Using System.Text.Json for JSON serialization/deserialization.

Any help or insights into why the deserialization is failing and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.
